# CGPath as a string

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, cgpath

Is there any way to get at the actual data of a CGPath, so it can be saved to a file and restored later?

And is there any documentation on how that data is structured?

I would like to write it as a string (like a SVG path string), or some way with the dictionary object and PList XML files, but I'll take what I can get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a post about saving `CGPathRef`s [here](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1312). The guy is using `CGPathApply` function to enumerate through the elements of the path:

```
static void saveApplier(void* info, const CGPathElement* element) {
    ...
}

...

NSMutableArray* a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
CGPathApply(path, a, saveApplier);
```